Baking Light onto existing Image Texture
I have a 3D-scan with an existing texture. I use blender to add some lighting. However, when exporting this as a .fbx to other programs or sites like sketchfab, the light intensity is always different. To circumvent this I wanted to bake the lighting onto the texture to ensure it displays the same across different programs/viewers.
While I think I understand the baking progress I am only able to replace the existing texture. Since there is no material assigned to the object, the result is a white texture with the lights instead of the texture I already had. Relevant tutorials only seem to cover baking procedurally generated textures.
How can I bake lighting onto an already existing image texture?
